# Laptop charger plugged in, but battery is stuck to a fixed percentage

Tags: dell, power-management, laptop, battery

This morning I noticed that even though I have my charger plugged in my Del (which is pretty new, like 3 months old), the battery remains stuck to a fixed value.

Seems like I can use it to infinity, the battery does not go any lower to 31% and does not go any higher.

[Screenshot of my power settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz4p6.png)

I tried powering off the computer, pressing the power button for 30 seconds, but the issue remained.
I have run the following commands:

```
    $ upower -i $(upower -e | grep 'BAT') | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"

    state:               charging
    time to full:        7.6 hours
    percentage:          31%
```

```
    upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1

      native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               Simplo
  model:                0x35,0x31,0x36,0x42,0x00,0x00,0x0006
  serial:               0006
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 29 Aug 2022 03:55:58 PM CEST (98 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              11.7225 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         41.0063 Wh
    energy-full-design:  41.0063 Wh
    energy-rate:         5.445 W
    voltage:             10.899 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    time to full:        5.4 hours
    percentage:          31%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-low-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1661781352  28.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1661781357  5.445   discharging
    1661781352  5.243   discharging
```

edit:
I have tried to use the laptop without the AC on, and the battery dropped from 31 to 28%.
Here are a few additional screenshots from the power statistics.
[power statistics screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwKJP.png)
[power statistics screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZyO7.png)

Do you think it's an hardware problem? Is it most likely to be about the cable or the laptop? Have you got some suggestions?

Thanks to anyone that answers!

Comment: did you try charging it with the laptop powered off? What happens? If you use a live USB, do you get a different battery reading? did you change any battery settings in BIOS? can you get a battery reading from your BIOS?

Comment: 1) I tried charging it when the pc was off. Nothing happened
2) I tried using a live Ubuntu distros from a USB pen. Nothing happened
3) I can't read battery infos in BIOS (no idea why)

Comment: Then it's a hardware issue of some kind, possibly the battery can't charge past 31%? Or you set your BIOS to force it to stay within a certain range of charge percentage. Or your BIOS is bugged and not reporting battery properly, even though it's actually charging. Hopefully it's still within warranty; contact Dell and ask for help. If it doesn't charge when completely powered down, it's not an OS issue.

Comment: the only thing that BIOS says is: "battery is working properly".
I have never touched BIOS settings, hence I doubt that the problem is there.

Comment: Contact Dell, if it isn't charging even when it's off most likely it's a hardware issue.